# How to make Outlook to go to the next unread email when deleting emails

Tags: email, ms-office, office-365

When deleting emails in Apple Mail it will automagically move the focus to the next **unread** email, basically it moves the focus up one line.

When deleting emails in Outlook for Mac it keeps the focus on the same line, so once the email is deleted the previous **read** email takes focus. And it does not matter if I press <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, it still shows the previous read email.

How can I setup Outlook to move the focus to the next unread email when deleting emails?

Comment: Apple Mail in fact moves automagically in the same direction you last moved manually [unless you are at one end of the list.] - maybe Outlook does the same, I can't test.

Comment: Suggest you contact the authors of Outlook... Not an Apple related question...

Comment: @SolarMike - Outlook is a macOS application, despite being created by the Microsoft Corporation. Should there be no way for the OP to go to the next unread email, [here's a site for Mac Outlook users](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac) where one can make enhancement requests.

Comment: @IconDaemon so is Apple responsible for the internal behavior of the application? Then it must be the authors...

Comment: From [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): _...third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products._ I've always interpreted this to mean software written for Apple computers and devices which has wide and common use.

Comment: → Rusl : Which keyboard are you using to get a [backspace] key? I deeply feel this is a keyboard function association problem and not at all an Outlook one.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I'm actually using Apple USB keyboard with number pad. It has both `backspace` and `delete` keys.

Comment: @Tetsujin No matter how I move the focus before or after deleting an email, Outlook still keeps highlighting a previous read email.